# Most important scriptures to understand hinduism

Tags: vedas, history, scripture

It's practically impossible for any individual to read and understand all the Hindu scriptures. What is the minimum set of scriptures which a person needs to read and understand the philosophy of Hinduism?

Comment: Hindusim is based on Sanathana dharma which is the way of life! Bhagavan Vyas divided small portion of infinite vedas into rug-yajur-sama-ardhavan vedas, there are many sub vedas under these. Since they cant be understood by commons, seers further simplified them into smritis, to further more simplify it they are re-worded with examples in puranas. Ramayana & Mahabharatha are the essence of them.

Answer (score 1):

If you strictly go for the minimum set ***'BHAGWAT GITA'*** contains all. It is the set of most important tenants to listen and perform as per *Sanatan Dharma*.

Further to clarify on your word 'It's practically impossible for any individual to read and understand all the Hindu scriptures.' You can read all, yes but understanding is a difficult job. Even understanding one line might take years, depending on your knowledge and perspective. To make this easy you need to acquire a Guru, *Bhagwat Gita* will not be able to do the 'most' good without him if your understanding and perspective both are small.